# Only show submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm trying to make a mobile menu. The plan is when you click a menu item the submenu shows, and the other menu items disapear, only showing the sub menu.

My code so far:

HTML

```
<div class="mobile">
    <div class="back"></div>
    <nav class="clearfix">  <a href="index.html" class="logo"></a>

        <button class="trigger">Menu</button>
        <ul class="menu clearfix">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a>Media</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="evenementen.html">Evenementen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="has-sub">    <a>Groepen</a>

                <ul class="sub">
                    <li class="terug"><a>&#60; Ga terug</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="groepen/piepers.html">piepers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="groepen/grovers.html">grovers</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="groepen/joros.html">joro's</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="groepen/knim.html">knim</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="groepen/sjo.html">sjo</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="groepen/+16.html">+16</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="groepen/+18.html">+18</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="over-ons.html">Over ons</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".mobile .trigger").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
        $(".mobile .menu").stop(true, false).fadeOut(250);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
        $(".mobile .menu").stop(true, false).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
$(".mobile .has-sub a").click(function () {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("clicked")) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).next().stop(true, false).fadeOut(250);
    } else {
        $(this).parent().addClass("clicked");
        $(this).next().stop(true, false).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
$(".mobile .terug a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().stop(true, false).fadeOut(250);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("clicked");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rings/03yhnmc9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've have found it: http://jsfiddle.net/Rings/03yhnmc9/1/

Updated jQuery:

```
$(".mobile .trigger").click(function()
    {
        $(".mobile .menu").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    });
    $(".mobile .has-sub > a").click(function()
    {
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("clicked");
        $(".mobile .menu li").not($(this).parent()).hide();
        $(this).next().children().show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $(".mobile .terug a").click(function()
    {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('> li').show();
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('> a').show();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very first attempt doing what you want, you can maybe hide/show the menu items with some animations instead.

jQuery

```
$(".mobile .has-sub a").click(function()
{
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("clicked"))
    {
        $(this).parent().removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).parent().parent().children().removeClass("hide");
        $(this).next().stop(true, false).fadeOut(250);
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent().addClass("clicked");
        $(this).parent().parent().children().addClass("hide");
        $(this).parent().removeClass("hide");
        $(this).next().stop(true, false).fadeIn(250);
    }
});
```

Then you need to add in your CSS the styles for .hide, for example:

```
.hide { display: none; }
```

From here on I think you can continue. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not completely the right answer, but this has made me thinking in an other direction, so thanks!